# Darknet Yolov4 Python memory leak

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, darknet, yolov4

I ran into a memory leak running `detect_image(...)` which is provided by [darknet.py](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet.py). I was detecting objects in an endless while loop. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.10, OpenCV 4.5.2 and Cuda 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

darknet.py already has a function to take care of this, namely `free_image(image)`. For some reason, this isn't called in the function `detect_image(...)` . I have added this underneath `free_detections(detections, num)` and the memory leak is taken care of. Here's the exact code:

````
def detect_image(network, class_names, image_path, thresh=.5, hier_thresh=.5, nms=.45):
    """
        Returns a list with highest confidence class and their bbox
    """
    pnum = pointer(c_int(0))
    image = load_image(image_path,0,0)
    predict_image(network, image)
    detections = get_network_boxes(network, image.w, image.h,
                                   thresh, hier_thresh, None, 0, pnum, 0)
    num = pnum[0]
    if nms:
        do_nms_sort(detections, num, len(class_names), nms)
    predictions = remove_negatives(detections, class_names, num)
    predictions = decode_detection(predictions)
    free_detections(detections, num)
    free_image(image) # this was missing...
    return sorted(predictions, key=lambda x: x[1])```
````

Comment: Actually, I just figured out that the code provided on AlexeyAB's GitHub is correct. I was using a modified darknet.py where the image is loaded from a given path inside the detect_image() function. My bad. Anyways, maybe somebody else stumbles across this modified version of darknet.py and will find this post useful. Unfortunately, after working through the night, I can't remember where I got the modified version from.